# Initialize values of a struct pointer

Tags: c++, struct, initializer

I am starting to learn binary trees in cpp and dynamically allocated memories;
thus to initialize a struct I do this

```
struct node{
    int val;
    node* left;
    node* right;
};
//Initialize:
node* root = new node;
root->val = 7;
root->left = NULL;
root->right = NULL;
```

I would like to know if there is a better way to set the struct values without writing the last  three lines of code.
I saw on some web pages that they do this:

```
int* n = new int(6);
```

Thanks!

Comment: yes thats called a constructor http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/85-constructors/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can write a custom constructor:

```
struct node{
    int val;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node(int);
};

node::node(int _v){
    this->val = _v;
    this->left = this->right = nullptr;
}

node *root = new node(6); // Works as you want
```

Or use member initializer list, which looks simpler:

```
struct node{
    int val;
    node* left;
    node* right;
    node(int _v) : val(_v), left(nullptr), right(nullptr) {};
};
```

Don't forget the braces after the list.

Comment: Have I been learning the wrong C++ all my life? This is the first I have heard of a custom constructor or a member initializer list for a struct.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to iBug's answer about using a constructor, if your object is a Plain Old Data type you can use aggregate initialisation to construct it using an initialiser-list, in the following manner, which avoids needing to define your own constructor at all:

```
node root = {7, nullptr, nullptr};
```

Or if you're allocating on the heap as you are doing:

```
node* root = new node{7, nullptr, nullptr};
```

You can have a look at this page on [aggregate initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/aggregate_initialization) for more information.

Comment: Yes, that works too, I'll keep it in mind, tank you, but in the case I am currently working I prefer the constructor.

Comment: What happens if your struct holds 3 pointers, but you construct it with the initializer list with only two arguments? Will it be NULL? Can I define a default value?